# Convert multi lined text to one line text and with symbol replacement

Tags: c#, string, text, data-conversion

I'm trying to submit a comment somewhere which accept only plain text and it must be within one line. My problem is that I don't know the type of format and how to do it in order to submit the comment.

For example new lines are replaced with \r\n, " is replaced with \" and so on. It depends on the symbol.

So my question is how to turn a illegal multi lined text into something plan and legal...

**For example turning:**

```
Here is the list:

"Pizza"

"Eggs"*
```

**Into:**

```
Here is the list: \"Pizza\"\r\n\r\n\"Eggs\"
```

Or at least what is this format called so I could do the research by myself.

Comment: this is called *escaping*, for the C# language it is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx). you will need to know all escaping rules of the service/app you're submitting to.

Comment: If you just want to replace some delimiter into a something else (or remove it) use [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) . If you want to split it into multiple strings use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *I don't know the type of format* ... it will be impossible to get it right if you have no or incomplete information about the target system. you need to know which characters it expects you to escape, which may not be escaped, and which kinds of escapes it supports (backslash, doubling, octal/hex unicode, ...)

Comment: It seems that there are just those two symbols to replace. The website is Youtube and it works very well with only those two symbols replaced, I asked the question by adding the answer too, haha. Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your list entries can have spaces in then you will need to take care with the order of the replacements.

```
var list = @"""Pizza"" ""Eggs"" ""Fish and Chips""";
var amendedList = list.Replace(@""" """, @"""\r\n""");
var amendedList2 = amendedList.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what you asked for:

```
        string[] toReplace = { "\"", " " };
        string[] with = { "\\\"", "\\r\\n\\r\\n" };
        string str = "Here is the list: \"Pizza\" \"Eggs\"";
        string toCheck = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(':') + 2);
        Console.Write(str + "\n");
        for (int i= 0; i < toReplace.Length; i++)
        {
            toCheck = toCheck.Replace(toReplace[i], with[i]);
        }
        Console.Write(toCheck + "\n");
```